# Mysql query involving multiple tables and an OR statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry in advance for an ambiguous title, but I can't think of a good one.

I have 2 tables:

```
bookings(booking_id, customer_id)
charges(customer_id, booking_id, amount)
```

where in charges table, either booking_id or customer_id must be entered. Not both.

I'm trying to get **amount** that are associated with a **customer_id**

Because the customer_id's are null sometimes in charges table, I have to use booking_id to acquire customer_id through bookings table.

So, I had a query like this:

```
SELECT c.amount
FROM charges as c, bookings as b
WHERE (c.customer_id = 1234) OR 
(c.customer_id = null AND c.booking_id = b.booking_id AND b.customer_id = 1234)
```

However, it seems to create an infinite loop.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are doing a `cross join` (cartesian product), based on the structure of your `where` clause.

A better approach is to use `left outer join` (and proper join syntax).  So, join to the `bookings` table, if it exists.  Then use `or` in the `where` clause to look for a match on the `customer_id` in either place:

```
SELECT c.amount
FROM charges as c left outer join
     bookings as b
     on c.booking_id = b.booking_id 
WHERE (c.customer_id = 1234) OR (b.customer_id = 1234)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a JOIN ? like

```
SELECT c.amout 
FROM charges AS c
LEFT JOIN bookings AS b ON c.bookin_id = b.booking_id
WHERE c.customer_id = 1234 OR b.customer_id = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT amount, customer_id from charges where customer_id = 1234
UNION
select amount, b.customer_id from charges c, bookings b where b.booking_id = c.booking_id and c.customer_id is null and b.customer_id = 1234
```